# Sample read/write handling of packets in C

Tags: c, networking, sockets, packet

I'm a bit new to C, but I've done my homework (some tutorials, books, etc.) and I need to program a simple server to handle requests from clients and interact with a db. I've gone through Beej's Guide to Network programming, but I'm a bit unsure how to piece together and handle different parts of the data getting sent back and forth.

For instance, say the client is sending some information that the server will put in multiple fields. How do I piece together that data to be sent and then break it back up on the server side?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking, "how does the server understand the information the client sends it"?

If that's what you're asking, the answer is simple: it's mutually agreed upon ahead of time that the data structures each uses will be compatible. I.e. you decide upon what your communication protocol will be ahead of time.

So, for example, if I have a client-server application where the client connects and can ask for things such as "time", "date" and can say "settime " and "setdate ", I need to write my server in such a way that it will understand those commands.

Obviously, in the above case it's trivial, since it'd just be a text-based protocol. But let's say you're writing an application that will return a struct of information, i.e.

```
struct Person {
    char* name;
    int age;
    int heightInInches;
    // ... other fields ...
};
```

You might write the entire struct out from the server/client. In this case there are a few things to be aware of:

1. You need to hton/ntoh properly
2. You need to make sure that your client and server both can understand the struct in question.
3. You may or may not have to align on a 4B boundary (because if you don't, different C compilers may do different things, which may burn you between the client and the server, or it may not).

In general, though, when writing a client/server app, the most important thing to get right is the **communication protocol.**

I'm not sure if this quite answers your question, though. Is this what you were after, or were you asking more about how, exactly, do you use the send/recv functions?

Answer (score 3):

First, you define how the packet will look - what information will be in it.  Make sure the definition is in an architecture-neutral format.  That means that you specify it in a sequence that does not depend on whether the machine is big-endian or little-endian, for example, nor on whether you are compiling with 32-bit `long` or 64-bit `long` values.  If the content is of variable length, make sure the definition contains the information needed to tell how long each part is - in particular, each variable length part should be preceded by a suitable count of its length.

When you need to package the data for transmission, you will take the raw (machine-specific) values and write them into a buffer (think 'character array') at the appropriate positions, in the appropriate format.

This buffer will be sent across the wire to the receiver, which will read it into another buffer, and then reverse the process to obtain the information from the buffer into local variables.

There are functions such as `ntohs()` to convert from a network ('n') to host ('h') format for a 'short' (meaning 16-bit) integer, and `htonl()` to convert from a host 'long' (32-bit integer) to network format - etc.

One good book for networking is Stevens' "[UNIX Network Programming, Vol 1, 3rd Edn](http://unpbook.com/)".  You can find out more about it at its web site, including example code.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above what you need is a previously agreed means of communication. One thing that helps me is to use xmls to communicate.

e.g. You need time to send time to client then include it in a tag called time.
Then parse it on the client side and read the tag value.

The biggest advantage is that once you have a parser in place on client side then even if you have to send some new information them just have to agree on a tag name that will be parsed on the client side.

It helps me , I hope it helps you too.